# All I ask is that my week start with Sunday again

Tags: macos, mac, calendar

[image: OS X Calendar widget showing weeks begging with Tuesday]

As much as I'd like Monday to start my weekend, I want to be on the same schedule as my boss for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Calendar go to Preferences > General and select Sunday in the drop down menu labeled "Start week on"

This setting will affect your Dashboard widget as well. You may need to close, and reopen the widget before you see the change take effect.